# Is it OK to use "get" instead of "did" with "a good turn"?

Tags: word-usage, usage

A good turn - favour.
A good turn - this phrase is usually used with 'do/did'.

Is it correct to say "We can **get a good turn** in return when we are in need."?

Can we use the word 'get'?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, **a good turn** is an idiomatic expression in its own right, for example

> one good turn deserves another. *- proverb*

In practice, it is usually used in the expression **Do *someone* a good turn**. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20me%20a%20good%20turn%2Cdid%20me%20a%20good%20turn%2Cdid%20him%20a%20good%20turn%2Cget%20a%20good%20turn%2C%20got%20a%20good%20turn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20me%20a%20good%20turn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdid%20me%20a%20good%20turn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdid%20him%20a%20good%20turn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20a%20good%20turn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20good%20turn%3B%2Cc0) shows how uncommon **get/got a good turn is**, and if you look at actual instances, none that I could find relate to this meaning.

The NGram also shows that the normal way of expressing receipt of a good turn is to say **... did me a good turn**.

The more normal way of expressing **can get a good turn** would be that somebody **owes me a favour**. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=owes%20me%20a%20favour%2C%20owes%20me%20a%20good%20turn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cowes%20me%20a%20favour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cowes%20me%20a%20good%20turn%3B%2Cc0) shows that **owes me a good turn** used to be common in the 1880's but in recent times **owes me a favour** is much more common.

Comment: Yes, but the question is how do you express somebody doing you a good turn. I don't think you can put the idiom into passive voice; you might have to say something like *They can do us a good turn in return.*

Comment: @PeterShor: I think that the NGram answers that point. I have now made it clear in the body of my answer as well.